# MongoDB in Docker drops databases automatically and periodically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a web page project developed in MEAN stack instanced in a server with Docker.

I have 2 container running, one has the API and the service, the other runs the mongodb service. Everything seems right but I have one big problem, in certain periods of time, the system drops my databases.

The last issue was on 11/03/2018 and the previous one 2 week ago.
These are the mongodb container last logs:

[image]

There is any configuration that maybe I can edit, or do you have passed through this problem?

If you need more information please do ask. Thanks.

Comment: Have you mounted a `volume` on the container to persist the data?

Comment: Yes! I did, I have 2 volumes (1 for mongo data and other for images).

Comment: do you know what server for ip address is 209.9.106.214 ?

Comment: I don'w know, but i searched for the other one (184.105.247.252) and google pops up an advice from The Shadowserver Foundation.

Comment: Do you have authentication enabled for your MongoDB? Is your MongoDB exposed publicly? It looks like an external user is connecting to your MongoDB service and is dropping the databases on purpose.

Comment: Hello @mbuechmann, I access to mongoDB without auth, maybe its exposed publicly. For sure you may me right, where can I configure these aspects?

Comment: Authentication is only one security measure. For a more complete list of security measures please review the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the MongoDB manual. In addition to authentication, I would also recommend enabling network encryption (TLS/SSL) and limiting network exposure with appropriate firewall configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database gets accessed from an external (public) IP. Your MongoDB server is publicly accessible and you have no authentication activated.

This official doc describes how you can enable authentication: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Furthermore: You can restrict access to the server. If your app server and your mongodb server are in the same network, you need not to expose your mongodb to the public.

Comment: I will try to configure the mongodb for only accept internal access. I made a noob failure. Maybe you are right and this is the reason. As soon I check it, I will upvote and accept the responde. Thanks.

Comment: Just to complete @mbuechmann answer, check [overlay networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)